# Clear all cookies from WebView

Tags: c#, cookies, webview, uwp

I am currently developing an application for Windows Phone 10 using UWP, in which I need a WebView that will set up several cookies in the process. The WebView can be instantiated many times, and I have noticed that the cookies do not get cleared on multiple instantiations, which makes it a bit difficult for my workflow (say, for instance, a user has to log in using the WebView, then when re-instantiating, the old state will be there).

I have tried using the [`clearTemporaryWebDataAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764996.aspx) to now avail. What is worse is that I don't know in advance the domains associated to the cookies, so I cannot do something like this:

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
HttpCookieManager cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager;
HttpCookieCollection myCookieJar = cookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri("https://url.com"));
foreach (HttpCookie cookie in myCookieJar)
{
cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
}
```

Is there anything in the API that might help me wipe out all the cookies for the WebView, or at least get a list of them so that then I can use `DeleteCookie` on each?

Answer (score 3):

> What is worse is that I don't know in advance the domains associated to the cookies, so I cannot do something like this:

AFAIK, there isn't a method for clearing cache data except [`ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync), but the code snippet you provided does clear cookies. For what you consider about don't know in advance the domains to the cookies, you may get the current navigating Uri by the `WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs` of [`NavigationStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_NavigationStarting) event handle. For example,

```
private void WebViewControl2_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    Uri gotouri = args.Uri;
    HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    HttpCookieManager cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager;
    HttpCookieCollection myCookieJar = cookieManager.GetCookies(gotouri);
    foreach (HttpCookie cookie in myCookieJar)
    {
        cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

And this will clear the cookies of current Uri. But this will clear the cookies every time the `WebView` navigates. You may need to set a flag to ensure if the `WebView` is a new instance depending on your app logic.

Another thing, in apps compiled for Windows 10, [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine to display HTML content. Clear cookies of current `WebView` instance may also clear others, which is same as you found cookies still exists when you have a new instance.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of something similar: just keep a "history" of all visited URLs and then when desired, loop through it and remove the cookies, but I am looking for a 'cleaner' solution (that for instance also takes care of third-party cookies).