# C# UWP clearing credential cache

Tags: c#, uwp, client-certificates

I'm developing an UWP app that is using webview and client certificate to login. I have a simple login frame that navigates to Webview frame. When I click login I'm navigated to webview and asked to select one of two certificates that I have in my certificate store. I select first one and I'm successfully logged in. I log out from webview application and navigate to login frame. Now I want to login again and choose a different certificate but I always log in with the first one I have selected. If I close app and start it again, it works like I want it should.

I have tried deleting AC\Microsoft\Crypto, AC\Microsoft\SystemCertificates and AC\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache but it doesn't work. I have also tried creating new instance of webview every time I navigate to webview frame but that also doesn't work.

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to clear cookie. Try to clean it with the following method.
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync();
Also check stackoverflow answer [Clear all cookies from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128225/clear-all-cookies-from-webview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still didn't work. Eventually, I've found this method public void ClearAuthenticationCache(). This does the trick.